# Is there any way to score the web/app page or the whole site/app like UX score?

Tags: usability, ux-field

There are some scores that we can calculate heuristics score, usability score(based on the pain points and affinity diagrams) but is there any way to calculate the overall website score or a particular web/app score like [AWWWARDS](http://awwwards.com) do for the UI?

If not then what are the things that we can calculate and are objective in nature?

Comment: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/quant-vs-qual/

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of SUS - the System Usability Scale that Pablo mentions. However, it really only covers usability and to some extent learnability. It also relies heavily on the subjective opinion of users at some point after a usability session, where users are unlikely to get a complete coverage of a product, or to be able to fairly compare a product with other similar products.

A rounded review of a website will rely on both qualitative and quantitative metrics. For many aspects of a site, there are no quantifiable metrics, so a qualitative view has to suffice, for example in areas of credibility or quality of search.

The only real way to get an impression for a broad range of diverse criteria is for a manual deep dive across as much of the product as possible.

Still - that's likely to generate a subjective result on the part of the reviewer unless they have a wide range of experience with reviewing other websites. In other words, given that a metric or an impression or a judgement must sit somewhere on a spectrum between two extremes, then the reviewer must know what those extremes are in order to asses the site in question. This might come from  experience, or by reviewing a bunch of other entries or looking at competitor websites in a given category.

That all means that it's next to impossible to have a consistent 'score' which you can give a website as an overall maetric. You can compare. You can build a relative impression. But you can't really say site A in a banking test scores 62, and site B in a gaming review scores 78, and contrast those metrics against each other sensibly. You might have a high expectation for the behaviour of forms on a banking website, but (maybe) not so much for a gaming website.

But what you can do is try to build some kind of fingerprint or profile for a type of website and compare like-with-like within the context of its peers.

Smahing Magazine has an [article on heuristic website reviews](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/a-guide-to-heuristic-website-reviews/) in which they describe exactly this process, using radar diagrams to visualize relative scores across different criteria.

From that article, here are some examples:

A radar plot showing poor performance across all heuristic categories.
[image]

A radar plot showing a website that performs well in all areas but one.
[image]

To emphasize the differences in the heuristic measurements, overlaying one radar plot on the other:
[image]

Note that even with such artefacts as these, the outcome from reviews are closely tied to the reviewer(s) and their individual approach to testing or reviewing, the depth to which they explore, the breadth of interaction, their familiarity with similar products, and their own set of expectations that they bring.

Answer (score 0):

You can track an experience across website measuring your own metrics such us Effectiveness, Efficiency, and Satisfaction. But if you are looking to **compare** your site's experience against the world's average, then using a framework such System Usability Scale or Net Promoter Score.

SUS Score has become an industry standard —mostly for big corps—. It's based on this 10 questions to get a average score of experience

> 1. I think that I would like to use this system frequently.
> 2. I found the system unnecessarily complex.
> 3. I thought the system was easy to use.
> 4. I think that I would need the support of a technical person to be able to use this system.
> 5. I found the various functions in this system were well integrated.
> 6. I thought there was too much inconsistency in this system.
> 7. I would imagine that most people would learn to use this system very  quickly.
> 8. I found the system very cumbersome to use.
> 9. I felt very confident using the system.
> 10. I needed to learn a lot of things before I could get going with this system.

Here are some other tips on how to make use of this questionnaire. Extracted from https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/system-usability-scale.html

> The participant’s scores for each question are converted to a new
>   number, added together and then multiplied by 2.5 to convert the
>   original scores of 0-40 to 0-100.  Though the scores are 0-100, these
>   are not percentages and should be considered only in terms of their
>   percentile ranking.
>
> Based on research, a SUS score above a 68 would be considered above
>   average and anything below 68 is below average, however the best way
>   to interpret your results involves “normalizing” the scores to produce
>   a percentile ranking.